# Time dimension in SSAS

Tags: time, ssas, dimension, msbi

I am trying to understand Time dimension is SSAS.

In SSAS we have an option to create Time dimension. I have two questions related to it

1. What difference it makes if i generate, Regular calendar, Fiscal
   calendar, Manufacturing Calendar or ISO 8601 Calendar?
2. Once the dimension is created, is it possible to update it. Let
   say i generated it for the range of 1 Jan 2012 to 31 DEC 2012 and
   now i want to increase it to 31 Jan 2013 is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to #1, but to #2, yes, you will be able to extend the range of your time dimension after it is created.